# CSV - java.util.scanner skip one value and select next value

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

if've got a small issue and hope you can show me a nicer way to solve it. So I'm reading in a CSV file using the scanner class.

```
scanner.useDelimiter("~");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.next();.equalsIgnoreCase("einfuegen_pdf")) {
        //then give me the next element, which is not ""
    }
}
```

In the CSV file which looks like shown below, I'm looking for the value after **"Einfuegen_PDF"**. In this case: **$Datei{MR-Test-PDF-01}**

```
~~~Einfuegen_PDF~~$Datei{MR-Test-PDF-01}~L~M~0~0~0~0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Till now my solution works, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to handle this.

```
scanner.useDelimiter("~");

List<String> csvContent = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
boolean hit = false;

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String element = scanner.next();

    if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("einfuegen_pdf")) {
        hit = true;
        count = 1;
    } else if (hit && count == 1) {
        count = 2;
    } else if (hit && count == 2) {
        csvContent.add(element);
        hit = false;
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice or solution.

So far

Comment: Reading CSV is a known activity.  Consider not reinventing the wheel and use an existing CSV library.  check out opencsv

Comment: Is it possible to read one line at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about scan per line and try the following.

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("~");
        String pdf = tokens[3];
        if (pdf.equalsIgnoreCase("einfuegen_pdf")) {
            csvContent.add(tokens[5]);
        }
    }
```

This will do less iterations through the loop.  The PDF file is at array index 3 and the CSV content you are looking for is at index 5.